# SwiftUI: Saving likes in CoreData for each individual cell

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do I save the like state for each individual cell? I decided to save via CoreData, but the like is saved for all cells at once.

In the Core Data model (LikedDB) there is an attribute such as `isLiked`

In the class there is a variable `isLiked`, which changes the state of the like:

```
class ModelsViewModel: ObservableObject{

    @Published var isLiked = false

    func like() {
        isLiked.toggle()
    }
}
```

This is how I save the like state from ModelsViewModel
And in label I use

```
struct CellView: View{
    
   //For CoreData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: LikedDBE.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \LikedDBE.name, ascending: true)]) var manyLikedDB: FetchedResults<LikedDBE>

    //For like
    @ObservedObject var cellViewModel: ModelsViewModel = ModelsViewModel()

    var body: some View{

        Button(action: {
        let likedDBE = LikedDBE(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        likedDBE.isLiked = cellViewModel.isLiked //I indicate that isLiked from CoreData = isLiked from ModelsViewModel()

        do{
            cellViewModel.like() //func from ModelsViewModel()
            try self.managedObjectContext.save() //Save
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }

        }, label: {
        Image(systemName: cellViewModel.isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart") //Here I use
           .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
           .foregroundColor(cellViewModel.isLiked ? .red : .black) //And here I use
})
```

And if I use `cellViewModel.isLiked`, then when I click like, the like is displayed only on the one I clicked on, but the state is not saved when restarting the application, if I use `likedDB.isLiked`, then the like is displayed on all cells at once, but the like is saved after restarting.

I want the like to be only on the cell I clicked on and it will be saved after restarting the application.

Comment: `@ObservedObject var cellViewModel: ModelsViewModel = ModelsViewModel()` Not related to CoreData.
Please read the question in more detail, below after the code there is more precise what exactly I want.

Comment: Too much missing code here to make a concrete suggestion. You have `cellViewModel.card = cardData` (even though you say it doesn't have to do with CoreData), but `ModelsViewModel` has no `card` property. `LikedDBE` isn't included at all, so it's unclear if saving the context will have any effect after a mutation. Please include a [mre].

Comment: I tried to make the question more compact, but I added the missing code to the question.

Comment: Why does `ModelsViewModel` have a reference to `Model` if it doesn't manipulate it at all? Also, `@Published` won't work with another nested `ObservableObject` unless you explicitly send `objectWillChange.send()`. `LikedDBE` still isn't included, so the likelihood of getting a concrete debug here is low.

Comment: `Model` is a class where I have attributes like: `name`, `category`, `price` and so on
That are not relevant to the main question. That 's why I didn 't specify.

Comment: If we can't build and run the code you have posted because you left something out, that code is relevant. Please read the link that was posted about minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: Okay, I changed it and now this code is clean

Comment: Until you understand how CoreData works you would follow the example that Xcode provides with a new project and then just pass the CoreData object directly into the child view as a parameter that wraps it in an `@ObservedObject`you are over complicating something that is very simple. Xcode gives you a sample project. You are updating the view model with the like function not the CoreData object.

Comment: I understand that now I have a `CellViewModel.isLiked`, which does not matter to CoreData, the thing is that in label I want to replace it with `likedDB.isLiked`

Comment: Wrap `likedDB` in an `@ObservedObject` in a subview.

Comment: You can write in more detail, I can't understand your comment a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer you need something like this.

```
Button("add", action: {
    //Create a new object
    let new: LikedDBE = store.create()
    //Trigger a child view that observes the object
    selection = new.objectID
})
```

It is a button that creates the object and triggers a child view so you can observe and edit it.

Long answer will be below just copy and paste all the code into your `ContentView` file there are comment throughout.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var store: CoreDataPersistence = .init()
    var body: some View{
        LikesListView()
        //This context is aware of you are in canvas/preview
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, store.context)
    }
}
struct LikesListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: CoreDataPersistence
    
    @FetchRequest( sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \LikedDBE.name, ascending: true)]) var manyLikedDB: FetchedResults<LikedDBE>
    //Control what NavigationLink is opened
    @State var selection: NSManagedObjectID? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(manyLikedDB){ object in
                    NavigationLink(object.name ?? "no name", tag: object.objectID, selection: $selection, destination: {LikeEditView(obj: object)})
                }
            }.toolbar(content: {
                Button("add", action: {
                    //Create a new object
                    let new: LikedDBE = store.create()
                    //Trigger a child view that observes the object
                    selection = new.objectID
                })
            })
        }.environmentObject(store)
    }
}
struct LikeEditView: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var store: CoreDataPersistence
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    //Observe the CoreData object so you can see changes and make them
    @ObservedObject var obj: LikedDBE
    var body: some View{
        TextField("name", text: $obj.name.bound).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        Toggle(isOn: $obj.isLiked, label: {
            Text("is liked")
        })
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading){
                    Button("cancel", role: .destructive, action: {
                        store.resetStore()
                        dismiss()
                    })
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                    
                    Button("save", action: {
                        store.update(obj)
                        dismiss()
                    })
                }
            })
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
struct LikesListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LikesListView()
    }
}

///Generic CoreData Helper not needed jsuto make stuff easy.
class CoreDataPersistence: ObservableObject{
    //Use preview context in canvas/preview
    //The context is for both Entities,
    let context = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCODE_RUNNING_FOR_PREVIEWS"] == "1" ? PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext : PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext
    ///Non observing array of objects
    func getAllObjects<T: NSManagedObject>() -> [T]{
        let listRequest = T.fetchRequest()
        do {
            return try context.fetch(listRequest).typeArray()
        } catch let error {
            print ("Error fetching. \(error)")
            return []
        }
    }
    ///Creates an NSManagedObject of any type
    func create<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T{
        T(context: context)
        //Can set any defaults in awakeFromInsert() in an extension for the Entity
        //or override this method using the specific type
    }
    ///Updates an NSManagedObject of any type
    func update<T: NSManagedObject>(_ obj: T){
        //Make any changes like a last modified variable
        save()
    }
    ///Creates a sample
    func addSample<T: NSManagedObject>() -> T{
        let new: T = create()
        //Can add sample data here by type checking or overriding this method
        return new
    }
    ///Deletes  an NSManagedObject of any type
    func delete(_ obj: NSManagedObject){
        context.delete(obj)
        save()
    }
    func resetStore(){
        context.rollback()
        save()
    }
    private func save(){
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var _bound: String? {
        get {
            return self
        }
        set {
            self = newValue
        }
    }
    var bound: String {
        get {
            return _bound ?? ""
        }
        set {
            _bound = newValue
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will sit and sort it out